# CODESYS problems with edge detection (bounce)

Tags: edge-detection, codesys

I have a problem with my CODESYS program. I have three buttons, which are defined as input. For each button a number is stored. For example the number 1. 
I have now created a program, which recognizes an edge on the button and stores the numerical value (2) of the button in an array. If you now press another button with the value (3), the value is also stored in a variable again. The two variables should be added together. 2 + 3 = 23. In my program I have the problem that if I press the button tester with the value 2, I get 22. This is wrong. I think the problem is due to the bruise of the push button. Several edges are detected. So I wanted to solve this software technically with a delay. Do you have any idea how I could program that?

CODE:

```
IF (PLC_PRG.calls[5].gpio = TRUE) THEN // edge detection on gpio
    IF (counter = 0) THEN // counter for the first value
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF

IF (PLC_PRG.calls[6].gpio = TRUE) THEN // edge detection on gpio
    IF (counter = 0) THEN // counter for the first value
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[6].message.floorstore[6]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[6].message.floorstore[6]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF

IF (PLC_PRG.calls[7].gpio = TRUE) THEN // edge detection on gpio
    IF (counter = 0) THEN // counter for the first value
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[7].message.floorstore[7]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[7].message.floorstore[7]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF


GlobalVar.floorstorage := concat(floorstorage2[0],floorstorage2[1]); // Total of value 1 and value 2 (1 + 2 = 12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement edge detection. Here is a code template you can use:

```
//  Generate Oneshot Signal 

VAR_INPUT
    SIGNAL : BOOL; // Input
END_VAR

VAR
    LATCH_SIGNAL : BOOL; // Latch
END_VAR

VAR_TEMP
    OS_P_SIGNAL : BOOL; // Oneshot - Rising edge detection
    OS_N_SIGNAL : BOOL; // Oneshot - Falling edge detection
END_VAR

//Code - Rising edge detection
OS_P_SIGNAL := SIGNAL AND NOT LATCH_SIGNAL;
LATCH_SIGNAL := SIGNAL;

//Code - Falling edge detection
OS_N_SIGNAL := NOT SIGNAL AND NOT LATCH_SIGNAL;
LATCH_SIGNAL := NOT SIGNAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the whole logic in a more object oriented way.

First, we define a Button.

Declaration part:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Button
VAR
    bSignal   AT%I* : BOOL;
    IButtonHandler : I_ButtonHandler;

    fbPushTimer : TON;
    fbTrig : R_TRIG;

    sValue : STRING;
END_VAR
```

Implementation part:

```
IF IButtonHandler = 0
THEN
    RETURN;
END_IF

fbPushTimer(IN:= bSignal, PT:=T#50MS);
fbTrig(CLK:=fbPushTimer.Q);

IF fbTrig.Q
THEN
    IButtonHandler.onPush(sValue);  
END_IF
```

The button has four properties:

---

1st Property:

Declaration part:

```
 PROPERTY getValue : String
```

Implementation part:

```
getValue := sValue;
```

---

2nd Property:

Declaration part:

```
PROPERTY isPushed : BOOL
```

Implementation part:

```
isPushed := bSignal;
```

---

3rd Property:

Declaration part:

```
PROPERTY setPushHandler : I_ButtonHandler
```

Implementation part:

```
IButtonHandler := setPushHandler;
```

---

4th Property:

Declaration part:

```
PROPERTY setValue : String
```

Implementation part:

```
sValue := setValue;
```

---

Then we define the interface.

```
INTERFACE I_ButtonHandler
```

and add the interface method:

```
METHOD onPush 
VAR_INPUT
    sValue : STRING;
END_VAR
```

At last we define the handler.

Declaration part:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_ButtonHandler IMPLEMENTS I_ButtonHandler
VAR_OUTPUT
    floorstorage : STRING;
END_VAR
```

The handler has two methods:

---

1st Method:

Declaration part:

```
METHOD onPush 
VAR_INPUT
    sValue : STRING;
END_VAR
```

Implementaion part:

```
floorstorage := concat(floorstorage,sValue);
```

---

2nd Method:

Declaration part:

```
METHOD reset
```

Implementation part:

```
floorstorage := '';
```

---

Now we need to init the buttons and call them in main.

Main declaration part:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR 
    aButtons : ARRAY[1..10] OF FB_Button;
    fbButtonHandler : FB_ButtonHandler;
    i : UINT;
    bInit : BOOL;
END_VAR
```

Implementation part:

```
IF NOT bInit
THEN
    FOR i := 1 TO 10 DO
        aButtons[i].setPushHandler := fbButtonHandler;
        aButtons[i].setValue := UINT_TO_STRING(i);
    END_FOR
    bInit := TRUE;
END_IF

FOR i := 1 TO 10 DO
    aButtons[i]();
END_FOR
```

You can choose your own button value depending on the button.

For simplicity, I assigned the loop index as the value of the button.

Each time the button is pushed, the method onPush gets called only once after 50ms.

When you want to access the value of *floorstorage* you simply call *fbButtonHandler.floorstorage* to assign it to another var.

By doing so you reach a stronger encapsulation and data protection for your variable than declaring it as *global*.

Comment: Where I have to define Interface?

Comment: Are you using Codesys 2 or 3?

Comment: https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_implementing_interface/

Comment: Interfaces and object oriented programming more in general work only with Codesys 3.

Comment: I have V3.5 Sp15 Patch 2

Comment: I added the property getValue in de FB Button. But I get an error with the property getValule: ';, :=, REF=, ( or [' expected instead of 'getValue'

Comment: Did you put PROPERTY getValue : String in the declaration part and getValue := sValue; in the implementation part?(double click on get to open the implementation part).

Comment: No, but I know now how to do it. The property isPushed is this Get or Set?

Comment: Get, you can delete the set part after you defined isPushed as a property.

Comment: Ok, I created the properties. And now ehre I have to define the Interface?

Comment: Look at the link I gave you under "Implementing an interface in a new function block".

Comment: You have to add the interface method after you created the interface.

Comment: Okay, so I created the Code. But I get 10 same errors: No VAR_CONFIG for 'PLC_PRG.aButtons[1-10].bSignal'. When I build the program I get no error. But when I want to login I get this 10 errors.

Comment: You need to map the variables to the process map:https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_variables_configuration/

Comment: If you don't have real hardware in your project replace the bSignal   AT%I* : BOOL; with bSignal : BOOL;

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any edge detection here

```
IF (PLC_PRG.calls[5].gpio = TRUE) THEN // edge detection on gpio
    IF (counter = 0) THEN // counter for the first value
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF
```

You check if the button is pressed. It means while you are holding this button this condition is true. It means that `counter` change it's state on every PLC cycle while you are holding the button. It means that if when you release button PLC made even number of cycles nothing will change and if odd number f cycles it will change. Here is how you detect a rising edge.

```
VAR
    xSignal, xSignalM: BOOL;
END_VAR

IF xSignal AND NOT xSignalM THEN
    // Raising edge is here
END_IF
xSignalM := xSignal;
```

This way condition will work only one PLC cycle and everything will be ok. So your code would look like this.

```
VAR
    M1, M1, M3: BOOL;
END_VAR

IF (PLC_PRG.calls[5].gpio AND NOT M1) THEN // edge detection on gpio
    IF (counter = 0) THEN // counter for the first value
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF
M1 = PLC_PRG.calls[5].gpio;

IF (PLC_PRG.calls[6].gpio  AND NOT M2) THEN // edge detection on gpio
    IF (counter = 0) THEN // counter for the first value
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[6].message.floorstore[6]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[6].message.floorstore[6]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF
M2 = PLC_PRG.calls[6].gpio;

IF (PLC_PRG.calls[7].gpio  AND NOT M3) THEN // edge detection on gpio
    IF (counter = 0) THEN // counter for the first value
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[7].message.floorstore[7]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[7].message.floorstore[7]; // save button value in the array to calculate the total
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF
M3 = PLC_PRG.calls[7].gpio;
```

Or you can use R_TRIG

```
VAR
    RT1:R_TRIG;
END_VAR

R1(CLK := PLC_PRG.calls[5].gpio);
IF (R1.Q) THEN
    IF (counter = 0) THEN
        floorstorage2[0] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5];
        counter := 1;
    ELSE
        floorstorage2[1] := PLC_PRG.calls[5].message.floorstore[5];
        counter := 0;
    END_IF
END_IF
```